# Passing parameters to a SignalR Hub (ASP NET Core 6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

how can i pass parameters to a asynchronous task of a SignalR Hub?

The paramaeters id, dis and dg have to be passes to the asynchronous task SendResults().

My hub:

```
public class ResultHub : Hub
{
    ResultRepository ResultRepository;

    public ResultHub(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        ResultRepository = new ResultRepository(connectionString);
    }

    public async Task SendResults()
    {
        int id = 2977;
        int dis = 3;
        int dg = 1;
        var Results = ResultRepository.GetResults(id, dis, dg);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedResults", Results);
    }
}
```

The asynchronous task SendResults gets the results with ResultRepository.GetResults.

SendResults is called in the Javascript within the chtml file:

```
function InvokeResults() {
    connection.invoke("SendResults").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}
```

and in the method TableDependency_OnChanged of the class SubscribeResultTableDependency

```
public class SubscribeResultTableDependency : ISubscribeTableDependency
    {
        SqlTableDependency<Result> tableDependency;
        ResultHub ResultHub;

        public SubscribeResultTableDependency(ResultHub resultHub)
        {
            this.resultHub = resultHub;
        }

        public void SubscribeTableDependency(string connectionString)
        {
            tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Result>(connectionString);
            tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_OnChanged;
            tableDependency.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;
            tableDependency.Start();
        }

        private void TableDependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Result> e)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType != TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.None)
            {
                resultHub.SendResults();
            }
        }

        private void TableDependency_OnError(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Result)} SqlTableDependency error: {e.Error.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Passing of parameters in the connection.invoke of the Javascript works, but how can this be done in both calls?

(Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.13)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to how to pass the parameter from the js to the Hub method, I suggest you could refer to below example:

1.Modify the hub method to add parameter, like below:

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendResults(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

2.Modify the js to add the parameter:

```
connection.invoke("SendResults", "parameter1", "parameter2").catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```